# overflow:hidden does not clip absolute positioned content

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to make a box with scrolling text inside. The problem is, when the text is halfway up the box, it is showing outside it when I expect it to be clipped.

The HTML/CSS is very simple and I have no clue what could be going wrong :

```css
#vbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #afa;
}
#vtext {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="vbox">
  <div id="vtext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
    <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
    <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>
    <p>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Isn't "overflow:hidden;" suppposed to hide the overflowing content ?

**Edit :**

Adding "postion:relative" to the box solves the issue but I'm still puzzled... Could someone explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Do you want to clip the text with scrolling or without scrolling? Not relevant to the question at hand, but it helps to be consistent.

Comment: Agree with you, and I don't understand how you are getting it. I am getting it cut. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/TnK7N/.

Comment: Hey, just found out that, to the parent, if you give `position: relative;` it gets cut: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/V98bg/8/

Comment: @Vandervals: Feel free to edit my answer as well. I'll be happy to approve it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Absolutely-positioned elements are not affected by any `overflow` setting if the element with that setting is not (or does not contain) its containing block (usually, this means it's not positioned).

In your case, the box is not positioned, so the text is anchored to the viewport instead of the box. The box doesn't know about the text and the viewport is large enough to contain the text, so no clipping occurs at all. You can find the gory details in [section 11.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping) of the spec.

Giving your box `position: relative` will cause the text to be positioned relative to the box, and be clipped as a result.

```css
#vbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #afa;
}
#vtext {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="vbox">
  <div id="vtext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
    <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
    <p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</p>
    <p>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! Now I understand what's going on.

Comment: @Loonie: You're welcome! You can mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark (you should be able to do this in another 5 minutes). Welcome to the site!

Comment: @BoltClock I don't understand. The `position: absolute`d element is inside the `overflow: hidden`d element right? In that case, when the abs element goes out of the dimensions, doesn't it get cut? Explain if I am wrong. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/TnK7N/ for the cutting edge! :P

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: The element with `overflow: hidden` itself is not positioned, so it won't affect the absolutely-positioned element. Once you make it `position: relative`, then it will affect it. In your case, you have `position: relative` on the parent, so it will clip the child.

Comment: Ah! Just got it. So, `position: relative` is the black sheep! :) Yeah, since that is not positioned, this won't get affected. Sorry buddy, didn't understand your answer correctly, till I tried it out. :P `+1` from my side too, as I learnt this thing, although I should have known it earlier. :)

Comment: I didn't believe anyone else can have such a problem :) Thanks for the solution

Answer (score -2):

Don't make the element inside the box `position:absolute`.

**CSS**

```
#vbox{
    width:100px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#afa;
}
.vtext{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

See updated http://jsfiddle.net/V98bg/4/